# Permitir que el archivo .gitignore deje subir una carpeta con los archivos que tiene dentro

Tags: git

Las rutas son `/storage/app/public/employees` y `/storage/app/public/projects`, `en /storage/app/public` tengo el archivo .gitignore.

¿Como puedo hacer para que ignore todo excepto esas dos carpetas?

Answer (score 3):

Para omitir todo excepto esos archivos específicos, puedes utilizar el símbolo `!`:

```
# Ignorar todo
*

# Pero incluir
!employees/*
!projects/*
```

[**`Documentación`**](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format)

> An optional prefix "**!**" which negates the pattern; any matching file
>   excluded by a previous pattern will become included again.
>
> Un prefijo opcional "**!**" que niega el patrón. Cualquier fichero
>   coincidente excluido anteriormente por otro patrón volverá a ser
>   incluido otra vez.